# Reliable way to detect if a column in a data.frame is.POSIXct

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

R has `is.vector`, `is.list`, `is.integer`, `is.double`, `is.numeric`, `is.factor`, `is.character`, etc. Why is there no `is.POSIXct`, `is.POSIXlt` or `is.Date`?

I need a reliable way to detect `POSIXct` object, and `class(x)[1] == "POSIXct"` seems really... dirty.

Comment: If you _do_ just check the class, `inherits` would probably feel cleaner.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I would personally just use `inherits` as [joran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412947/reliable-way-to-detect-if-a-column-in-a-data-frame-is-posixct#comment41473978_26412947) suggested. You could use it to create your own `is.POSIXct` function.

```
# functions
is.POSIXct <- function(x) inherits(x, "POSIXct")
is.POSIXlt <- function(x) inherits(x, "POSIXlt")
is.POSIXt <- function(x) inherits(x, "POSIXt")
is.Date <- function(x) inherits(x, "Date")
# data
d <- data.frame(pct = Sys.time())
d$plt <- as.POSIXlt(d$pct)
d$date <- Sys.Date()
# checks
sapply(d, is.POSIXct)
#   pct   plt  date 
#  TRUE FALSE FALSE 
sapply(d, is.POSIXlt)
#   pct   plt  date 
# FALSE  TRUE FALSE 
sapply(d, is.POSIXt)
#   pct   plt  date 
#  TRUE  TRUE FALSE 
sapply(d, is.Date)
#   pct   plt  date 
# FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 21):

The `lubridate` package has `is.POSIXt`, `is.POSIXct`, `is.POSIXlt`, and `is.Date` functions.

Comment: Of course.  I'm trying to do this in base R and forgot about lubridate.

Comment: If `x <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())`, then `is.POSIXt(x)` is `TRUE` even though `x` is not POSIXct...

Comment: `is.POSIXt` returns TRUE if the class is either `POSIXlt` or `POSIXct`.

Comment: Yes, that was my point. It does not help you differentiate between POSIXct and POSIXlt.

Comment: Clarification added. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can try `is()`.  This is what the `lubridate` functions `is.Date` and `is.POSIX*` rely on anyway.

```
x <- Sys.time()
class(x)
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
is(x, "Date")
#v[1] FALSE
is(x, "POSIXct")
# [1] TRUE

y <- Sys.Date()
class(y)
# [1] "Date"
is(y, "POSIXct")
# [1] FALSE
is(y, "Date")
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Not that it really matters in this case, but `inherits` was designed for S3 and goes straight to C code, while `is` needs to handle S4 and makes several calls to other R functions.